# Validating Date of birth in C++

Tags: c++, time.h

I have just started learning C++.
While going through the codes on this site I came across a code which validates date entered by the user.But that problem is that it can take even future values , thus this logic needs to be tweaked in order to work for accepting DOB.
so I decided to take the current time using "time()" function and then comparing it with the entered date. To start with, I added two lines in the code (the ones which are commented in the below code) which are

```
time(&tNow);
```

and

```
const struct tm *now = localtime(&tNow);
```

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
// function expects the string in format dd/mm/yyyy:
bool extractDate(const std::string& s, int& d, int& m, int& y){
    std::istringstream is(s);
    char delimiter;
    if (is >> d >> delimiter >> m >> delimiter >> y) {
        struct tm t = {0};
        t.tm_mday = d;
        t.tm_mon = m - 1;
        t.tm_year = y - 1900;
        t.tm_isdst = -1;

        // normalize:
        time_t when = mktime(&t);

        time_t tNow;

      //   time(&tNow);

          const struct tm *norm = localtime(&when);

      //  const struct tm *now = localtime(&tNow);       /* when I uncomment this line the code                              
      //                                                   does not accept future date   */



      // validate (is the normalized date still the same?):   
        return (norm->tm_mday == d    &&
                norm->tm_mon  == m - 1 &&
                norm->tm_year == y - 1900);
    }
    return false;
}


int main() {

    std::string s("11/01/2015");
    int d,m,y;

    if (extractDate(s, d, m, y))
        std::cout << "date " 
                  << d << "/" << m << "/" << y
                  << " is valid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "date is invalid" << std::endl;
}
```

When I uncomment the `const struct tm *now = localtime(&tNow);` the code gives correct output as "invalid date" for any future date values...but why is this happening.I am getting correct output but I want to know why.

Comment: Sounds like you've been hitting undefined behavior somewhere, I just can't actually spot where. Did you get any warnings when compiling?

Comment: I am using online compiler (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php) to compile this code and its not giving any errors, it is working fine

Comment: no it is not showing any warnings.

Comment: [I can confirm the same behavior on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6a3e7a7a2aca08a)

Comment: You probably need to COPY the result from `localtime`, as it returns the pointer to a local static variable. So when you call it gain, you get the same pointer (you can check this by inspecting the pointer itself when it is returned).

Comment: @Mats: well it says so in [the documentation for `localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)!

Comment: @Jongware: Indeed, as it SHOULD.

Comment: Your code may be about validating a DoB, but your question is not about that at all - consider changing the title to reflect your question rather than your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that `localtime` returns the same buffer when you call it multiple times. You need to copy the result (or use `localtime_r` which takes an extra parameter, but it's not quite as portable).

Here's my debug session of your code (with uncommented section):

```
(gdb) p norm 
$1 = (const tm *) 0x7ffff75aca60 <_tmbuf>
(gdb) p now
$2 = (const tm *) 0x7ffff75aca60 <_tmbuf>
```

The way I solved it is this:

```
  const struct tm norm = *localtime(&when);

  const struct tm now = *localtime(&tNow);


  // validate (is the normalized date still the same?):   
  return (norm.tm_mday == d    &&
      norm.tm_mon  == m - 1 &&
      norm.tm_year == y - 1900);
```

There are several other variants on the same theme, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Most `localtime()` implementations use an internal local static `struct tm`.  The pointer returned is a pointer to this single instance, so inn your case `norm` and `now` point to the same `struct tm` instance, and the second call modifies it.

Some implementations may use *thread local storage* so that usage in different threads at least gets a separate `struct tm`, but that would not affect this case, and is not required behaviour.

Most [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) is clear on this, for example the reference linked says:

> The returned value points to an internal object whose validity or value may be altered by any subsequent call to gmtime or localtime.